# Error: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1 position 1

Tags: c#, xml

Getting above error while loading a local XML file. In app setting, I am using below path.

<add key="Resources" value="D:\DataBackup\DataBackup\UnconfirmTransactionService\UnconfirmedTransactions\Resources"/>

While execution reaches at xml.LoadXml(_filePath)  exception occur as :

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

How to resolve this issue?

```
string SMStext = string.Empty;
try
{
    string _resource = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Resources"].ToString();
    string _filePath = _resource + @"\SmsTemplates.xml";
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(_filePath);
}
```

Tried to change the path. Checked file is available or not in path.

Comment: do you have maybe a hidden BOM char??

Comment: have you checked if that file is a `well formed` XML file ?

Comment: You are using the wrong method. `LoadXml` expects an XML-string not a filename ...